# Why is XML I'm passing via AJAX to an MVC controller not getting there?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an XML string from the HTML/JavaScript client side to the ASP.NET MVC server side. The problem is that the XML string never reaches the server, whereas an ordinary "non-XML" string will be successfully transferred.

The relevant JavaScript code on the client side is the following:

```
function TransferXmlDataToServer() {
    var sXml = "<Tag>This is an XML test string.</Tag>"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("TransferXMLData", "Home")',
        data: { sInputXml: sXml },                             
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(sReturnValue) {
            alert("Value returned from server is: " + sReturnValue);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("There was an error on the server side");
        }
    })
};
```

This is the corresponding function in the MVC Home controller on the server side:

```
public JsonResult TransferXMLData(string sInputXml) {
    // The arguments' name must match those used in the View's Ajax call
    return Json("Success");
}
```

When the *TransferXmlDataToServer* is invoked from the client side, the *There was an error on the server side* message is displayed. I have put some debugging printing statements in the *TransferXMLData* on the server side that are not invoked, showing that one does not even enter in this function.

On the other hand, when

```
sXml = "<Tag>This is an XML test string.</Tag>"
```

is replaced by

```
sXml = "This is a test string."
```

everything works as expected.

Additional notes:

- This was tried with IE11 and Edge.
- I tried to convert the XML string to Serialized Json prior to sending it to the server, to no avail.

I would greatly appreciate knowing what I am doing wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default asp.net protects against content that looks like HTML mark-up being sent to a controller action un-encoded. You need to decorate your action with the [`ValidateInputAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to let the content through:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult TransferXMLData(string sInputXml) 
{
    // The arguments' name must match those used in the View's Ajax call
    return Json("Success");
}
```